# Connecting external monitor logs out computer

Tags: display

When I connect an external monitor via VGA, the computer logs out (not just screen lock). I can see the lock screen on both the monitors with low screen resolutions on both. When I enter the password, the screens go blank, and it again comes back to lock screen. When I remove the VGA cable, the resolution is still low on my laptop. Then when I enter the password, I get back the lock screen again, this time with correct resolution. *Now* when I enter the password, I log in to the computer with all the previously running programs closed. I have also tried booting up while the VGA is already connected, but that too gives the same result. I was using this monitor with no problems on Ubuntu 14.04 previously on the same machine.

I am using OS 0.3.2 Freya (64-bit). I have a Nvidia GeForce GT 750M graphics card, but I am using the Nouveau driver. The monitor I am connecting is an LG Flatron with a resolution of 1440x900.

Comment: While on the lock screen press CTRL+ALT+F1.Then login and run `startx`.Add the output of the command

Comment: @SuiciDoga I ran the startx command and saved the output to a txt file. But I am limited by the maximum comment length to post it here. Can you tell what part of the output is relevant?

Comment: Add a link to a cloud storage like Dropbox or Google Drive

Comment: Here you go - https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/55945990/startx_out.txt

Comment: Can you also add the file /var/log/Xorg.1.log

Comment: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/55945990/Xorg.1.log

Comment: _This looks like a job for Bug Report!_ All jokes aside, I suggest reporting this as a bug, seeing as this is rather unusual behaviour and likely specific to elementary OS.